# Error deploying CLR udf project in VS - system.core 3.5 not found in SQL catalog

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-3.5, clr, clrstoredprocedure

I am building CLR Stored Procedures and UDFs as discussed in this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CLR_Stored_Procedure.aspx

When I execute Build > Deploy, I get the following error:

> Error: Assembly 'system.core,
>   version=3.5.0.0, culture=neutral,
>   publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089.' was
>   not found in the SQL catalog.

Note that I am using some classes in .NET 3.5.

How can I fix this? I am deploying to Sql Server Express, but in prod it will be Sql Server 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer:

http://weblogs.asp.net/paulomorgado/archive/2009/06/13/playing-with-sql-server-clr-integration-part-iv-deploying-to-sql-server-2005.aspx